# Next.js return the 404 error page in getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript, next.js

Currently I am following this example on how to redirect users in getInitialProps

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/Redirecting-in-%60getInitialProps%60

The problem is, if I want to return 404 like this, it will return a blank page instead of the usual Next.js 404 error page.

```
context.res.writeHead(404)
context.res.end();
```

Please note I know using ExpressJs and using statuscode 404 works, however, for this project I am not allowed to use ExpressJs so I need to use typical nodejs writeHead to do it.

Comment: Next.js 10 makes this super simple, find up to date answer below

Answer (score 56):

Next v10 allows to return 404 page (not with props, but just plain as it is below)

```
  if (!checkItem) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }
```

Full code that works for me: ✅✅✅

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(async ({ req, res, locale, query, store }) => {
  const { productId, categoryId } = query
   
  const checkItem = await getProductBySlugSSR(productId, categoryId, store)

  if (!checkItem) {
    return { // <-----------------does the trick here!!
      notFound: true
    }
  }
    
  return {
    props: {
      ...await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common']),
    }
  }
})
```

Documentation: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#notfound-support

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of 2021. (Next.js v10.2)

Comment: @Vadorequest no, the OP was asking for `getInitialProps`, but not found support is only available for `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps`

Comment: Where does `wrapper` come from?

Comment: @Newbyte it comes from: 

import { HYDRATE, createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper' 

export const wrapper = createWrapper(initStore)

Comment: This is the true answer for 404 problem

Answer (score 25):

In order to do that, you’ll have to render the Error page in your page.

You can do something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ErrorPage from 'next/error'

class HomePage extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps(context) {
    try {
      const data = await retrieveSomeData()
      return { data }
    } catch (err) {
      // Assuming that `err` has a `status` property with the HTTP status code.
      if (context.res) {
        context.res.writeHead(err.status)
      }
      return { err: { statusCode: err.status } }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { err, data } = this.props

    if (err) {
      return <ErrorPage statusCode={err.statusCode} />
    }

    /*
     * return <Something data={data} />
     */
  }
}
```

If you have a custom error page, instead of importing `next/error`, you’ll have to import your custom `_error` page.

Answer (score 7):

Implement your getInitialProps along the lines of:

```
    static async getInitialProps(context) {
        const {res} = context;

        ...

        if ([something went wrong]) {
            if (res) {
                res.statusCode = 404;
            }

            return {
                err: {
                    statusCode: 404
                },
            };
        }
        ...
```

Then in render() check if `err` is defined in state, in which case return the ErrorPage (default or custom one, depending on your implementation) and that's it! The statusCode inside err is just for more granular message on the ErrorPage so it needs to be passed for it as props.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I do it

```js
import ErrorPage from 'next/error'

const Mycomponenet = () =>{
   if (!exists) {
        return <ErrorPage statusCode={404}/>
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of NextJS 10, you can now include `notFound: true` in the return object of `getStaticProps && getServerSideProps` to redirect to the 404 page

Here are the release notes: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#redirect-and-notfound-support-for-getstaticprops--getserversideprops

Answer (score 1):

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node'
import Error from './_error'

require('es6-promise').polyfill()
require('isomorphic-fetch')

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}
    let e
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      try {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
      } catch (error) {
        e = error
        Sentry.captureException(error) //report to sentry
      }
    }
    return { pageProps, e }
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, e } = this.props
    if (e) {
      return <Error /> // customize your error page
    }
    return (
      <Container>
        <Head>
          <title> Your title</title>
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

This works like a charm ~ 
just try catch in next/app, then it works for all the pages

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to implement the **404 PAGE** like you do in **cra**

the code provided can be helpful:
eg.

```
 import AComponent from '../acomponent';
 import Error from '../error';
  
 const User = (data) => {

   return data.id ? <AComponent /> : <Error />
 }

 User.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
   const res = await fetch(...data) // list of items = []
   const data = await res.json()

   return data;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new AppRouter, you can use the `NotFound()` function:

See the NextJS docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found

```js
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'
 
async function fetchUser(id) {
  const res = await fetch('https://...')
  if (!res.ok) return undefined
  return res.json()
}
 
export default async function Profile({ params }) {
  const user = await fetchUser(params.id)
 
  if (!user) {
    notFound()
  }
 
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using this and it works for me

```
res.sendStatus(404)
```